# Match a single character in a string bash script

Tags: bash, string

My issues is that I want to read a character from the stdin and compare it with a string value. If that character exists then I want to display a message. Eg, saving `%` into the variable `$a`:

```
$ read a
%
$echo $a
%
```

There is variable defined say `` v='~`!@#$%^&*()_-+=:;{[}]|\/<>,."' ``
all possible special character including single tick `'`

I need to check if the character input exists in the string value. How can I do this.

Answer (score 2):

```
case $v in
  *"$a"*) printf '<%s> is in <%s>\n' "$a" "$v"
esac
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go:

```
#!/bin/bash
v='~`!@#$%^&*()_-+=:;{[}]|/<>,."'
echo type any character and press enter
IFS= read -r a
[[ $v =~ "$a" ]] && echo match || echo not
```

Comment: Janos, I didn't know how to run this from the script:

[[ $v =~ $a ]] && echo match || echo not

Comment: @NirmalArri save the script for example in `script.sh`, and run it with `bash script.sh`

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
cat | egrep -e '[~`!@#$%^&*()_-+=:;{[}]|/<>,."]'
```

Comment: What are you `cat`ing here? Did you mean something like `echo "$a" | grep -E ["$v"]`?

Comment: No, not quite: the first `]` marks the end of the set.

Comment: @Giles You're correct hadn't noticed that!

Comment: @terdon I just typed a couple of test lines straight into cat, but agree your use of variables closer to question.